# How to pass file, BytesIO, StringIO in Python to be used later?

Tags: python, io

These three memory or disk buffer follow the same access pattern. I'm going to focus `BytesIO`.

**How do I pass in a file or buffer object to be used later?**
I'm having a lot of trouble with the following use case:

```
def get_file_and_metadata():
  metadata = {"foo": "bar"}

  with io.BytesIO() as f: 
   f.write(b'content')
   f.seek(0)
   return f, metadata

f, metadata = get_file_and_metadata()

# Do something with file 
pd.read_csv(f, encoding="utf-8")
```

I suspect is because `f.close()` is ran after return statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`close` is run when the `with` suite terminates. If you want to pass back an open file-like object, you should not open it in a `with`. One option is to just drop the context manager completely and leave it up to the caller to clean up the object.

```
def get_file_and_metadata():
    metadata = {"foo": "bar"}
    f = o.BytesIO() 
    f.write(b'content')
    f.seek(0)
    return f, metadata

f, metadata = get_file_and_attr()
try:
    # Do something with file 
    pd.read_csv(f, encoding="utf-8")
finally:
    f.close()
```

This is a reasonable thing to do any time a file object is passed through some sort of pipeline or used in an order that makes context managers inconvenient. 99% of the time files are closed when the object deleted anyway, at least in cpython.

Or you could write your own context manager

```
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def get_file_and_metadata():
    metadata = {"foo": "bar"}
    f = o.BytesIO() 
    f.write(b'content')
    f.seek(0)
    try:
        yield f, metadata
    finally:
        f.close()

with get_file_and_attr() as f, metadata:
    # Do something with file 
    pd.read_csv(f, encoding="utf-8")
```

From your comment I realized that the metadata could just go on the BytesIO object and then its context manager is available.

```
import io

def get_file_and_metadata():
    metadata = {"foo": "bar"}
    f = io.BytesIO()
    f.write(b'content')
    f.seek(0)
    f.metadata = metadata
    return f

with get_file_and_metadata() as f:
    pd.read_csv(f, encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for thank you! Followup on your context manager, can you not just use with `with get_file_and_attr() as f, metadata:` without using contextlib decorator or yield syntax?

Comment: `with` requires an object with `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods. `contextlib.contextmanger` converts a generator into a context manager (adds those special methods). So, you could turn `get_file_and_attr` to a class and add those methods or use [`contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager). Just realized I didn't to it quite right... fixing now.

Comment: Thanks, this confirms my suspicion hence why I returned a tuple. If only a buffer or file object was returned then you don't need the contextmanager syntax (since buffer/file object has `__enter__` and `__exit__` already).

Comment: That's a good point and so I added yet another way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`with` keyword will automatically close the file once out of it's context i.e. out of the with code block (hence it is called a context manager).

Instead, create a file_obj and return that.

```py
def get_file_and_metadata():
  metadata = {"foo": "bar"}

  f = io.BytesIO() 
  f.write(b'content')
  f.seek(0)
  return f, metadata

f, metadata = get_file_and_metadata()

# Do something with file 
print(f.read())
f.close()
del f # to remove it from memory.
```